# Custom Comparator : Need Explanation

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

Can some one explain me how comparator works? I mean when someone use return a-b or for example took from here (http://buttercola.blogspot.com/2015/08/leetcode-skyline-problem.html) :

```
 public class EdgeComparator implements Comparator<Edge> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Edge a, Edge b) {
            if (a.x != b.x) {
                return a.x - b.x;
            }

            if (a.isLeft && b.isLeft) {
                return b.height - a.height;
            }

            if (!a.isLeft && !b.isLeft) {
                return a.height - b.height;
            }

            return a.isLeft ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
```

Say for example, here why they are using a.height - b.height ? or b.height - a.height ? Please explain me.

Comment: No one can know this. These variable names are terrible - what is `x`? What is `height`? What is `isLeft`? How are the edges being compared? What makes one edge "bigger"? The longer edge? What has `isLeft` got to do with it?

Comment: Do you understand what a `Comparator` is used for? And what the `compare()` method should return? - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `a-b` is a shortcut to `Integer.compare(a, b)` because *in the absence of overflow* it returns a positive number when `a > b`, zero when `a == b`, and a negative number otherwise. `b-a` reverses the direction of the comparison, returning a negative when `a` is *greater* than `b`.

However, the subtraction approach breaks down due to overflow when the two numbers are of large magnitude, so one should use [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) instead:

```
public class EdgeComparator implements Comparator<Edge> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Edge a, Edge b) {
            int res = Integer.compare(a.x, b.x);
            if (res != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            if (a.isLeft && b.isLeft) {
                return Integer.compare(b.height, a.height);
            }
            if (!a.isLeft && !b.isLeft) {
                return Integer.compare(a.height, b.height);
            }
            return a.isLeft ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: From the link he posted, "It is guaranteed that 0 ≤ Li, Ri ≤ INT_MAX, 0 < Hi ≤ INT_MAX, and Ri - Li > 0". In that case overflows are not possible.